# How do I notify incoming scene when presentScene:transition: is complete?

Tags: core-animation, sprite-kit

Let's say I'm transitioning from an old `SKScene` of an `SKView` to a new one:

```
//In some controller somewhere...
-(void)swapScenes{
  MySceneSubclass *newScene = [[MySceneSubclass alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(1024, 768)];
  SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition crossFadeWithDuration:REALLY_LONG_DURATION];
  [[self mySKView] presentScene:newScene transition:transition];
}
```

Let's additionally say I want my new scene to perform some action or animation once the transition is completed, but not before. What would I use to trigger that?

At first I thought I'd be able to override `didMoveToView:` to do this, but it turns out this is called at the very begining of the transition (in hindsight, this makes sense. In a crossfade, the incoming scene is composited at the very beginning of the animation, even if its opacity is very low).

Next, as a hail mary, I tried inserting a call to the new scene right after `presentScene`:

```
-(void)swapScenes{
  MySceneSubclass *newScene = [[MySceneSubclass alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(1024, 768)];
  SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition crossFadeWithDuration:REALLY_LONG_DURATION];
  [[self mySKView] presentScene:newScene transition:transition];
  [newScene doSomethingAfterTransition]; //<----
}
```

But `presentScene:` predictably returned immediately causing this method to be called long before the transition had completed.

As a last resort, I'm considering something like:

```
[newScene performSelector:@selector(doSomethingAfterTransition) afterDelay:REALLY_LONG_DURATION];
```

But I'd really like to avoid that if at all possible. It seems like there ought to be an delegate action or notification or *something* that knows when the transition is over, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to this was staring me in the face. As I mentioned above, in a transition both scenes need to be present throughout the animation. Thus the incoming scene's `didMoveToView:` is called immediately at the beginning of the transition instead of at the end as I expected.

Of course, by this same logic, the *outgoing* scene's `willMoveFromView:` won't get called until *the end of the transition*. Which is what I was looking for in the first place.

So, you can override `-willMoveFromView:` of the outgoing scene (or, more likely, some shared superclass) to send a notification or call a delegate or whatever you like when transition completes. In my case, I have it call a block so I can keep everything local to my `-swapScenes` method, but YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

Perform selector after delay with the same delay as the transition is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Reasonable, maybe. But *explicitly* not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why? It works, there aren't any drawbacks and scheduling a selector with the duration of the transition is the only solution.

Comment: "Scheduling X at *n* and Y at *n+1*" is a very imperative approach. "Telling Y to happen after X" is declarative. Why does declarative programming trump imperative? Years from now, when I go searching for the code that displays a menu after a transition, I won't remember to look for "that thing that just happens to be scheduled to run `REALLY_LONG_DURATION` later." I appreciate your answer (I even voted it up), but I do say in my question it's not what I want to do.

Comment: Well, the only other possible solution I can think of is ensuring the new scene is paused during the transition, and then wait for the first time the update: method runs which will be right after the transition ended. Besides, what could be so crucial to timing that it has to happen just when the transition ends? Does it even matter if it occurs a couple ms earlier or later? The user certainly won't notice that the new scene's opacity hasn't reached exactly 1.0 when the event fires. At 0.9 it would be just as well.

Comment: I don't know what to say. The difference between imperative and declarative programming has nothing to do with whether an event "occurs a couple ms earlier or later." It's a *conceptual* difference that strives for greater simplicity and maintainability. Anyway, as it happens I've discovered a solution. I'll write it up when I have a moment.

Comment: A conceptual difference that makes no tangible difference in this case. You can even make it declarative by hiding the perform selector after delay in a presentScene wrapper that automatically and always calls the same method after the transition duration. Anyway I'm curious to see what solution you came up with.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41907/discussion-between-jemmons-and-learncocos2d)

Comment: for what it's worth, if the action is not timed correctly it can cause the transition to stop before it's completed

Answer (score 2):

This is a commonly desired need and (ideally) we shouldn't be programming around the tools.  The two workaround provided by @jlemmons and @LearnCocos2D are both functional, but each have their fallbacks.

I would highly suggest going to the Apple Bug Reporter and requesting the addition of

```
- (void)[SKScene didFinishTransitionToView:(SKView *)view]
```

The more people request, the sooner it *may* appear.